# how to query dataframe and rdd without schema

Tags: pyspark

How to load csv file `without any schema` into spark rdd and 
dataframe and assign the schema

#### I have a file with the data like this

```
AA,19970101,47.82,47.82,47.82,47.82,0
```

#### the schema should be

```
stockname,date,highprice,lowprice,openprice,closeprice,volume
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can first create rdd for the input data and on top of the rdd you can create dataframe with schema.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import *

rdd = sc.textFile("//path/to/textfile/file.txt")

schema = StructType([
            StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
            StructField("created_at", TimestampType(), True),
            StructField("updated_at", StringType(), True)
            ])

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```